# How do I detect if an armour stand has something on its head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to know how to detect if an armour stand has a helmet on its head.
By that, I mean any item, such as a player head or other item.
I already tested something like :

```
execute as @e[type=armor_stand,nbt:{ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"player_head",Count:1b}]}]
```

But unfortunately, this is not working. How can I make it work?

(I'm porting this to a data pack if anyone is curious)

I am in 1.16.5.

Comment: What have you tried already, and which edition of Minecraft?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ArmorStand have helmet on head". Do you mean by them having an armorstand on their head, or a helmet on their head? Please edit your question so we can understand your question better to help you.

Comment: Voting to close until version is stated. If you state your version and maybe even a little more info I'm sure me and others would be happy to reopen it (if/ *when* it does close).

Comment: And which version of Minecraft are you using?

Comment: i am using 1.16.5 version

Answer (score -1):

Well a way to test this would be to use the replace item command, as you might already know, when a command block is executed it emits a redstone signal, so you could have a command block running to test if there is a helmet on the armor stand, you can do this by constantly replacing the armor stands helmet piece with air, and once someone puts a helmet on it, it will emit a redstone signal and then be removed. Here's the command:

```
/replaceitem entity <target> slot.armor.head air 1
```

Just make sure there is a slight delay between the time the helmet is placed and the time the helmet is removed. If you have any further questions feel free to ask me.